# GO cobra: space separated values in StringArray flags

Tags: go, go-cobra

In GO's Cobra, lib for making CLIs, there are two input flags accepting multiple values being passed. One of the options is `StringArray`, when used as follows:

```bash
--flag=value1 --flag=value2
```

it yields an array `["value1", "value2"]`.
I am working on a drop-in replacement for a tool that expects somewhat more complex input:

```bash
--flag=valueA1 valueB1 --flag=valueA2 valueB2
```

the array it should yield would be `["valueA1 valueB1", "valueA2 valueB2"]`

is there a way in cobra to parse the entire string until the next flag and include it in StringArray value like above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way in cobra to do this, as there will be ambiguity. For example, in the case when there is also a sub-command  named `valueB1` or `valueB2`, it's not clear whether those should be executed as subcommands or interpreted as additional argument to `--flag`.

The standard way to support an input like this is to expect the the input values are quoted, and cobra supports that. E.g.:

```
--flag="valueA1 valueB1" --flag="valueA2 valueB2"
```